# Environment variable expansion not longer works in npm run on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, environment-variables, package.json, variable-expansion

I have npm scripts that use environment variables. Here is an excerpt of `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "staging": "npm run deploy -env=staging",
    "deploy": "winrs /r:intranet /d:F:\\wwwintranet\\deploy npm run build -env=%npm_config_env%",
```

Until now, `-env=%npm_config_env%` was expanded to `-env=staging` or whatever. Suddenly it stopped working. Probably this is due to an update to npm from 6.x to 7.x.

When I test with `"deploy": "set & winrs /r:intranet /d:F:\\wwwintranet\\deploy npm run build -env=%npm_config_env%"`, I can confirm that the variable is still set.

As a temporary solution, downgrading npm to version 6.x (`npm install -g npm@6`) helped. Nevertheless, I need a solution that will work also in the future.

How can I enable variable expansion again for npm 7.x ? Or what are the alternatives for passing environment variables with npm 7.x ?

**Edit**

This was a bug in npm 7.5.x. It is fixed in npm 7.7.0 and above (see https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2731)

Comment: It may be related to [this rfcs](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md). However, does changing `"staging": "npm run deploy -env=staging"` to `"staging": "npm run deploy --env=staging"`, _(i.e. prefix `env` with double hyphens)_ make a difference?

Comment: @RobC Yes, reading the npm-rfc you link, I think this might be the issue, but contrary to what is stated there, the environment variables are well set in *Windows cmd* (see the  `set` commande in the question), but they are not expanded. And no, double hyphens have no influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failure to expand environment variables on Windows appears to be [a recent high-priority known bug in the npm CLI](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2731).

There are several options to use as a workarounds until a fix is released.

- You can downgrade to version 6.x until this is fixed.
- This won't work for your specific case (see below), but for most cases, you can use `npx` to use `npm@6`:

```
npx -p npm@6 npm run deploy
```

- You can try downgrading to an earlier version of 7.x to see if the bug has always existed in 7.x or not. Start with 7.0.0 and go from there.

The `npx` suggestion won't work here because `deploy` invokes `npm` itself and that will use `npm` from your `PATH` which is `npm@7`. But for generic cases where you need to invoke an old version of `npm` in narrow cases, that will work.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find this bug report

Comment: The `npx` solution will not work not work the way you suggested, because the variable expansion does not work when parsing that line. I will test if it work, when I use it here `"staging": "npx -p npm@6 npm run deploy -env=staging"`. I'll update the question once I tested this.

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround with `npx` does **not** work.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. You can still use `npx` that way from the command line and it will almost certainly work. So in this case: `npx -p npm@6 npm run deploy` and leave `package.json` unchanged from what you have originally. I'll update the answer to say that instead.

Comment: Oh, wait, but the package.json runs npm and may pick a different npm than the one being run by npx. Hmmm.... Yeah, that still won't work for your case  but will work for any cases that don't involve invoking `npm` from the `npm-script`.